# How to search by international classification at USPTO

Tags: uspto, patent-search, classification

I am trying to get list of granted patents searched by class at http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm

I am trying the following string.
Anybody have any Idea how to do this.

```
icl/C07 AND icl/A61
```

It is showing 0 reslts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Truncation for classification as you are not using complete classification.

> e.g. icl/c07$   AND icl/a61$